# CsGo, disconnect before kick final scoreboard

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I was playing with four premade players, and finished second in the team.  They decided to kick me as soon as the final scoreboard was shown, for giggles I suppose.  I quickly noticed and typed `disconnect` in the console before the vote was completed.  What happens in this scenario?  In "My Matches" it says "You Won This Match."

Comment: There is no penalty for leaving in final scoreboard. No idea about kicking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kicking and Leaving during the Final Scoreboard of a Match yields no penalty for a player. How do I know? The group I play with does it almost every match. **So that game will indeed count as a win.**

Comment: Great, but is it considered a tally on my " kick tally"?

Comment: I do not know this as a fact but I don't think it does. It'd be weird if it would, especially seeing that you left the game before the vote was even completed. And according to some steam forum posts i found valve has made it so that if you get kicked by 4 premades who are friends with each other on steam, the kick will not count towards you "kick tally" (I do however not know if this is true / still applies)